# How to send complex string via AJAX

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

I have to send a complex string via AJAX in ASP.NET MVC from my view to a particular controller action.

The string needs to contain all sorts of characters like < , > , & , " , ' .

I am using the following code in javascript :

```
var request = new Sys.Net.WebRequest();
request.set_url("/Controller/Action?Param=" + str) ; // str is the string to be sent
request.set_httpVerb("POST");
request.invoke();
```

But when I run the page, the AJAX request does not reach the action in the controller.

Can anyone tell how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[use encodeURIComponent on str](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp)

```
var request = new Sys.Net.WebRequest();
request.set_url("/Controller/Action?Param=" + encodeURIComponent(str)) ; // str is the string to be sent
request.set_httpVerb("POST");
request.invoke();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [`Server.UrlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525738.aspx). or just plain [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)/[`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) in javascript.

Encode the raw data before appending it to the URL.

Answer (score 1):

create your delete method in global.asax like this

```
routes.MapRoute("Delete", //Route name
                "ControllerName/MethodName/{id}",
                new { controller = "controller Name", action = "Method Name", id = 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
request.set_url("/Controller/Action?Param='" + str+"'"+) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you jQuery. Microsoft AJAX is like stone age and totally deprecated in ASP.NET MVC. I mean if you was working on some legacy ASP.NET WebForms application you would have had an excuse but in ASP.NET MVC there is no excuse. So:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<%= Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { Param: str },
    success: function(result) {
        // handle the success
    }
});
```

Also if you need to send special characters such as `<`, `>`, ... you must ensure that the corresponding controller action is decorated with the `[ValidateInput(false)]` attribute:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Action(string Param)
{
    ...
}
```

and if you are using ASP.NET 4.0 you might also need to set the following in your web.config for this to work:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```